# I have an onEdit function that I need to search for an unchecked checkbox from a row of checkboxes [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

About my spreadsheet:

- Cell B1 to the final column of row 1 are full of checkboxes.
- Column A from rows 5 to 16 are full of checkboxes.

What I need from this macro:

- I want to create an onEdit function that runs when the checkboxes in cells A5:A16 are checked.
- I want it to start by going through the checkboxes in row 1 and finding the first unchecked checkbox.
- Then I want it to identify that column so that the value in that row (ie. the row of checkbox that was just checked) and column (ie. the column of the first unchecked box in row 1).
- I want to take the value in this cell and to deduct it from the value in row 17 of the same column.

Here is a link for an example of my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xet-VnYidcVitRx4ffjimXBjGNDQoYl2SbaxfIUJV7A/edit?usp=sharing

My attempt so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  //This IF statement ensures that this onEdit macro only runs when cells A5:A16 is edited
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "Finances 2020" &&
    e.range.getColumn() == 1 &&
    5<=e.range.getRow()<=16
  ) {

    //Cells A5:A16 are checkboxes. This section ensures the following script only runs when the checkbox is checked (and not when unchecked).
    var checkboxtest = e.range.getValue()
    if (checkboxtest == true) {

      //THE ABOVE HAS BEEN TESTED AND WORKS SUCCESFULLY.
      //I CANNOT GET THE FOLLOWING TO WORK:


      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var Finances_2020 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Finances 2020");
      var Billrow = e.range.rowStart
      //Deduct the value in the first unchecked column of the edited row, from the value in row 17 of that same column:
        var AllFortnightCheckboxes = Finances_2020.getRange(1, 30, 1).getValues();   //Create a variable consisting of all the values in the row 1 checkboxes. This is used to find the first unchecked box.
        for(var i=0; i<AllFortnightCheckboxes.length ; i++){  //This For loop will run through all of the row 1 checkboxes.
          if (AllFortnightCheckboxes[i] == false){        //This if statement will look for the first unchecked box.
            //Copies the value to row 17 of that column:
                   //*******I have not been able to test the above before writing this bit of script. Once I have identified the column of the first unchecked box in row 1, I should be able to create this section.
            //Stop once the first unchecked checkbox has been found:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
;
```

Comment: Need a sample sheet link, it is not clear enough what you are asking for. Looks like this can be entirely done without scripts but I need a sample input output sheet.

Comment: Try this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xet-VnYidcVitRx4ffjimXBjGNDQoYl2SbaxfIUJV7A/edit?usp=sharing

Link also added to the body of post.

Comment: Just as I suspected, I have no idea what you want to happen when you check the box, please rephrase it in one sentence. Just give me one simple example... tell me what to check and uncheck and tell me exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: The OP wants the script to trigger on column 1 between rows 5 and 16 to establish the working row and then the OP wants to find the first unchecked checkbox in row 1 that's the working column.  Then take the value at row 17 and the working column and subtract from it the value at working row and working column.  It's pretty clear.

Comment: @Cooper It's just very confusing, I don't understand why making a script for this is a good idea? If I keep unchecking and checking it will add value over and over again. What is the purpose of doing it this way? Does he mean for these checkboxes to act as buttons?

Comment: I don't think using onEdit is a good idea.  I never do.  But that's a question for the OP not me.

Comment: @Nagaram92 if you clarify exactly what you want, I might be able to clarify how to do this without inEdit at all, but it looks like Cooper's answer is fulfilling exactly what you asked for even though what you are doing does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="Finances 2020" && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>4 && e.range.rowStart<17 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    var rA=sh.getRange(1,3,1,sh.getLastColumn()-2).getValues()[0];//flattened
    //Logger.log(rA);
    for(var i=0;i<rA.length;i++) {
      //e.source.toast('flag3');
      if(rA[i]==false) {
        //e.source.toast('flag4');
        var col=3+i;
        sh.getRange(17,col).setValue(sh.getRange(17,col).getValue()-sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,col).getValue());
        break;//stop after first one
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, I am clicking the checkboxes what is supposed to be happening?

Comment: Just tried it, still not doing anything for me, the toast works when uncommented though. I really don't understand how these checkboxes are supposed to work.

Comment: I made several changes.  Maker sure you're using the last one.